# Google Maps InfoWindow shows up on wrong Map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, infowindow

My Problem is in the WP-Plugin I write that when there is more than one map open on the same time,
e.g. on the mainpage where the last 3 posts are shown each with an own minimap showing their position, 
that when I click on one of the markers, doesn't matter from which map, the infoWindows will show up all in the last map...

I initialize the maps with the following code:

```
function Initialize(lat, lng, zm, pid) {    
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: zm,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }

    var name = "map_canvas" + pid;  

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(name), mapOptions);
}
```

and set the markers as followed:

```
function AddMarker( lat, lng, address, title, link, image, target ) {

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
        icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage( image ),
        title: title
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ 
        content: '<a href="' + link + '" target="_' + target + '">' + title + '</a><br /><small><font color="#000000">' + address + '</font></small>', 
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.open(map,marker);
    });
}
```

the `var map` stands on top of the functionfile, kinda like a Global, so that the markers are all on the right map, but sadly the infowindows won't follow them...

does anyone else experienced such stuff, or has an idea how I can solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
});
```

Accesses the `map` variable when the map is clicked not the value of the variable when you assign the handler. Pass a copy and use that instead:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (m) {
    return function() {
        infowindow.open(m,marker);
    };
}(map)));
```

Edit:

The above uses an immediately invoked function expression to pass in a copy of the `map` variable. All this does is declare a function and then immediately call it, passing in `map`.

```
function (m) {
    return function() {
        infowindow.open(m,marker);
    };
}(map)
```

However, the whole thing needs to be wrapped in `()` so that the JS parser reads it as a function expression and not a function declaration.

Another way of solving it would be:

```
function AddMarker( lat, lng, address, title, link, image, target ) {

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
        icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage( image ),
        title: title
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ 
        content: '<a href="' + link + '" target="_' + target + '">' + title + '</a><br /><small><font color="#000000">' + address + '</font></small>', 
    });

    // Add a function that returns a new function that uses a local
    // copy of the passed in map.
    var getMapClickListener = function (m) {
        return function () {
            infowindow.open(m, marker);
        };
    };

   // Then use the new function when adding the handler.
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', getMapClickListener(map));
}
```

Comment: ah okay.. that explains it... I thought they get the reference at the same time like the markers...

Comment: but could you explain that code? that syntax is kinda weird.. where exactly did he got the right map from? from the marker?

Comment: I'll add an update in about an hour, until then Google IIFE and see if you can figure out what's happening!

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that while you're assigning the map name to `name` correctly using the `pid`, each map is then being assigned to the `map` variable, each one overriding the other.

What you might find useful is using an object to hold your maps using the pids as keys:

```
var mapHolder = {};
var name = "map_canvas" + pid;
var mapHolder[pid] = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(name), mapOptions);
```

That way you can access each map without hassle just by passing in the `pid` to the `addMarker` function:

```
function AddMarker( lat, lng, address, title, link, image, target, pid) {

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: mapHolder[pid],
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
    icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage( image ),
    title: title
  });

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: // content
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.open(mapHolder[pid], marker);
  });

}
```

That way all your markers and infowindows should open on the correct map.